# Labelling points in 3d scatter

Tags: matlab

I have a series of highly-dimensional points. When plotting them in 2D, I can highlight clusters in different colors/markers using:

```
gscatter(new_data(1,:),new_data(2,:),trainlabels,[],'<x+*sdv^o>ph.')
```

I would like to do the same with a 3D scatter, but understand that a gscatter3 function doesn't exist and scatter3 doesn't allow me to specify a label set...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command [text](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html)(x,y,z,str) to label your points in 3D.

```
scatter3(pointList(1,:),pointList(2,:), pointList(2,:));
text(pointList(1,:),pointList(2,:), pointList(2,:), trainlabels[]);
```